# New line is not working with jspdf and result being overridden

Tags: json, jspdf

On Submit of form Json data will be generated I want to convert it into PDF. I'm using jspdf, almost everthing is working fine except each key and value of json or not rendering in new line.I have refrerred some of solutions as "\n" .its working when its kept individually but not within "for loop".any suggestions and refrence would be highly appreciated. Thanks in Advance

```
<form class="form" id="formOne" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname"><br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname"><br>
  <button type="submit" value="submit" id="submitOne"> add </button>
  <br>
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
   var json = {}
   function ConvertFormToJSON(form) {
   var array = $(form).serializeArray();
   $.each(array, function() {
   json[this.name] = this.value || '';
 });
 return json;
}


  $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".form").on("submit", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var jsonArray= ConvertFormToJSON(this);
   var doc = new jsPDF();
   doc.text(20, 30 + (10), jsonArray['firstname']+"\n"+jsonArray['lastname']);//working
   for (var key in jsonArray) {
   doc.text(20, 30 + (10), key+"\n"+jsonArray[key]+"\n");//not working
   }
    doc.save('Test.pdf');
    });
  });
  </script>
```

in pdf file result has been overriding

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by increasing 'y' co-ordinate value on each iterate of the loop. the doc.text() function accepts x and y co-ordinates as parameters.The solution will be

```
            var i=1;
            var doc = new jsPDF();
              for (var key in jsonArray) {
                     i++;
                     doc.text(10, (i*10) + (10), key + ":" + jsonArray[key]+"\n");
              }
```